# Subform To Return all records containing a string in Master Form

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I cant think of anyway to do this, but I'm working on a `database` set up in 1995 with re-occurring customers with some having slightly different names and my client wants all records that contain the customer name to be displayed in a subform. This is only a `flat file database` with the fields

```
Job_Number (pk), Customers, Date, and details
```

I set up a subform with a simple `master child link` to the `Customer` field and the subform returns all records matching the `customer name`, but not all records that contain the string Customer.

Is there any way to do this, I don't want to have to set up a separate Customer table and find all the unique customers, because this database has 15000 records.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use linked fields. Instead use the `On Current` event of the main form to set up a filter on the sub-form and `Requery` it. Example:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.SubFormName.Filter = "Customers LIKE '*" & Me.CustomerName & "*'"
    Me.SubFormName.FilterOn = True
    Me.SubFormName.Requery
End Sub
```